# Amend footer information

Tags: 8, blocks, configuration

My company site has moved from D7 to D8 this morning. It all looks great (and so much easier to use!), but I can't see how to amend a footer? One of our office buildings changed its name during the migration earlier this week, so I just need to change one word. In the D7 site, I used to be able to hover over the field and click on the cog icon to amend the copy in the footer, but I can't find how to do this anywhere on Drupal 8. Any ideas?

Comment: In-place editing is a Drupal 8 core feature. Check if the module *Quick Edit* is enabled. If it is still not working then it could be an issue with a custom theme not printing entity/field attributes.

Comment: ... and check that the user role has the permission *Access in-place editing*.

Comment: And even if the in-place editing isn't working you can always get to the admin page where you can change Blocks through Structure > Block layout > [Active theme].